# Generate YAML schema from dataclass in Python

Tags: python, yaml, schema, intellisense, ruamel.yaml

Suppose I have the following dataclass:

```py
@dataclass
class MyStocksConf:
    File: str = r'buydicnk.cache'
    SrcFile: str = "example_mystock.csv"
    PortofolioName: str = "My Portfolio"
    Use: Union[UseCache, int] = UseCache.USEIFAVALIABLE
```

I have a class config that is a dataclass and contains it (and other classes).

I register the custom classes using ruamel.yaml. Though I eventually load it unsafe.

I want to have IntelliSense in YAML (using yaml-ls). For this I need to generate a schema. This schema should positively match this:

```yaml
MyStocks:
 !MyStocksConf
 File: buydicnk.cache
 PortofolioName: My Portfolio
 SrcFile: C:\Users\...\.compare_my_stocks
 Use: !UseCache DONT
```

The definition of `UseCache`:

```py
@to_yaml
class UseCache(int,Enum):
    DONT=0
    USEIFAVALIABLE=1
    FORCEUSE=2
```

How would I generate such a schema from my class definition?

I want to have the types in the schema. If it is an enum, also the members of the enum as it is forcing. Other things are unknown to the schema generator, although arguably the description could be deduced from the description of the fields.

PS:

This is the generated schema. It can still be improved by having the enum accept names.

```
{'$defs': {'UseCache': {'enum': [0, 1, 2], 'title': 'UseCache', 'type': 'integer'}}, 'proper
ties': {'File': {'default': 'buydicnk.cache', 'title': 'File', 'type': 'string'}, 'SrcFile':
 {'default': 'example_mystock.csv', 'title': 'Srcfile', 'type': 'string'}, 'PortofolioName':
 {'default': 'My Portfolio', 'title': 'Portofolioname', 'type': 'string'}, 'Use': {'anyOf': 
[{'$ref': '#/$defs/UseCache'}, {'type': 'integer'}], 'default': 1, 'title': 'Use'}}, 'title'
: 'MyStocksConf', 'type': 'object'}
```

Comment: Can you show the concrete result you want to get in this example?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, I think you want to get IntelliSense (autocomplete, parameter info, etc.) in VSCode when editing YAML files, and you want it to know about the `MyStocksConf` class. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Not vscode , but yes. If it can validate it , it is better.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Just in short (giving the yaml scheme itself won't do any good): for each parameter, I want it to type it correctly . For the first three, just string in this case without further constrained. For the UseCache, it should list the different options(it is an enum).

Comment: And how would that look like?

Comment: The yaml scheme, whatever as long as it works. The yaml : ```    MyStocks: !MyStocksConf
      File: buydicnk.cache
      PortofolioName: My Portfolio
      SrcFile: C:\Users\...\.compare_my_stocks 
      Use: !UseCache DONT
```

Comment: I edited that YAML into your question where it's more readable. I also changed the last sentence; people are welcome to suggest tools/packages/etc. in their answers, but questions [aren't supposed to ask for them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (see #3).

Comment: Also the YAML you supplied doesn't match the defaults listed in your class definition, or the same class name. Is that just an oversight or am I missing something?

Comment: ...Actually wait do you even want the values listed in the YAML, or just the types?

Comment: The last edit was generally an improvement but a bit misleading. I just added an example for YAML(not the scheme). So it is not the default one. Fixed anyway.

Comment: I wanted to have the types in the scheme, if it is an enum, also the members of the enum as it is forcing. Other things are unkown to the scheme, although arguably description could be deduced from the description of the fields.

Comment: Can you please **show** the schema you want to generate (not any other YAML file that also matches the scheme)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pydantic supports generating schema. You can work with it instead of normal dataclasses.

So you can do:

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyStocksConf:
    ...
```

```py
from pydantic import TypeAdapter

adapter = TypeAdapter(MyStocksConf)
print(adapter.json_schema())
```

See:
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/json_schema/

Notice that AFAIK, JSON scheme is used to validate YAML.